# How to restrict Alphabets using Keyup Function?

Tags: jquery

I have an input box need to restrict alphabets in keyup function.

I used ASCII value to prevent them.

```js
$('.numbers').keyup(function(e) {
  if (((e.which > 47) && (e.which <
      58)) || (e.which == 46) || (e.which == 8)) {
    console.log("success");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="height" class="numbers" value="172" type="text" name="height">

<input id="weight" type="text" class="numbers" value="55" name="weight">
```

I need to Restrict the alphabets in my input box.

Comment: I think you must use keydown, because key was input into textbox already, before keyup!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML text input allow only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.numbers').keypress(function(e) {
  var x = e.which || e.keycode;
  if ((x >= 48 && x <= 57) || x == 8 ||
    (x >= 35 && x <= 40) || x == 46)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="numbers" />
```